# How can we get Replication Factor and Retention Hours of the Topic using Apache Kafka API

Tags: apache-kafka

How can we get Replication Factor and Retention Hours of the Topic using Apache Kafka API?

I am using version 0.9 and figured how to use AdminUtils to get number of paritiions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already familiar with the the AdminUtils it's not that far to go. Get the config of the topic you are interest in. You'll get a map with all configuration items of this topic. At least in kafka 0.8.x the key for the retention configuration was "retention.ms". So let's try this one (Disclaimer - This is unchecked code):

```
val zkUtils = ZkUtils(zkConnectionString,
                      30000,
                      30000,
                      JaasUtils.isZkSecurityEnabled())
val configs = AdminUtils.fetchEntityConfig(zkUtils, ConfigType.Topic, topicName)
val retention = configs("retention.ms")
```

Comment: That worked (to some extend), but all it is returning is just the {retention.ms} property and nothing else. And it is not returning this info for all topics.